# Always show [The post image must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png, webp.] laravel

Tags: laravel

It always shows error in validation. I tried uploading png jpeg jpg and all showed error.

View

```html
<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="post_image_container">
     <input type="file" name="post_image[]" id="post_image" class="bg bg-light border rounded text-dark font w-100 p-3 form-control" placeholder="Add Images" accept="image/*" multiple>
     @if($errors->first('post_image'))
         <small class="form-text d-block text-danger fw-bold">{{ $errors->first('post_image') }} 
         </small>
     @endif
</div>
```

Controller - Validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'post_title' => ['required', 'min:5'],
            'post_tags' => ['required', 'min:5'],
            'post_content' => ['required', 'min:50'],
            'post_image' => ['required', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,webp']
        ]);
        dd($request->all());
```

[image: When I try to remove the validation and dd the form]

Comment: I tried to search for answers here at SO but they all don't work. I also tried to put image in the 'post_image' validation but the error changes to "The file must be an image" something like that

Comment: try adding the ```image``` validation to ```post_image```, like this ```'post_image' => ['required', 'image', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,webp']```

Comment: In your input why do you have ```name="post_image[]"``` and not ```name="post_image"```. Are you uploading multiple images? That might be the issue

Comment: You are asking for `post_image` but you are sending an array in `post_image` because you wrote `post_image[]`....

Comment: Thanks. I solved it, those are partly the problem. and doing this in the validator fixed it `'post_image.*' => [etc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading multiple images, therefore, you need to state that in your validating by writing this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'post_title' => ['required', 'min:5'],
            'post_tags' => ['required', 'min:5'],
            'post_content' => ['required', 'min:50'],
            'post_image' => ['required', 'array'],
            'post_image.*' => ['required', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,webp'],
        ]);
```

Comment: notice that you have to loop through your `$request->post_image` to process what you need to do next.